# How to compare values in a 1d array to a 2d array in c++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'd like some assistance on comparing values of two arrays of different dimensions.

```
float gain[21][3]; // job_count is 21 and processor_count is 3
float numbers[MAX];
int arraysize = 21; // job_count = arraysize

// It a one dimensional sorted array
cout << "Sorted Numbers:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
  cout << numbers[i] << endl;
}

// It is a 2 dim array
for (int i = 0; i < job_count; i++) {
  // cout << "Job: " << i + 1 << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < processor_count; j++) {
    if ((j + 1) == (jobs[i].processor_exec + 1)) {
      cout << " " << endl;
    } else {
      gain[i][j] = {(jobs[i].criticality *
                     (1 - (1 - jobs[i].reliability) *
                              (1 - jobs[i].processors[j].new_reliability))) -
                    (jobs[i].criticality * jobs[i].reliability)};
      if (numbers[i] == gain[i][j]) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " is the Maximum gain is found for "
             << "Job" << i + 1 << "on Processor" << j + 1 << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I need to compare each value of the numbers array with each value of gain array and return the appropriate job id and processor id for the matching values. The above code does not get inside the if statement. Even if i hard code like :-
if(numbers[0] == gain[1][2]) // When I know numbers[0] and gain[1][2] both have same values.
still not working.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What is the code supposed to do? What are the inputs? What are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Here's a tip for helping with [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/): Split up complex expressions into the smallest part possible, storing values in temporary values. That will make it easier to see the intermediate results when stepping through the code in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: I am sorry, but this question contains all that I dislike: most of the code is unrelated to the question and the code is not self contained (uses a lot of variables that are defined elswhere). To correctly understand the question and be able to provide a relevant answer, we need a [mre]. That way we can 1/ reproduce the problem and then 2/ propose a fix.

Comment: The code is supposed to compare the values of numbers array(1d in nature) with the values of the gain array which is 2d in nature. For example if i have an input of a value like 0.7 in numbers array then it should find the same value i.e 0.7 from the gain array and return its appropriate index of job_count. Expected output is a match found and actual output is that it is not printing anything as not going inside the if statement.

Comment: Can this be be done :- (numbers[i] == gain[i][j]) . if not then how to compare?

Comment: Why `(j + 1) == (jobs[i].processor_exec + 1)` and not `j == jobs[i].processor_exec`?

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). It is extremely unlikely that the calculation of `gain[i][j]` is going to produce exactly the `float` you're looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: On an unrelated note: why do you believe that the arrays are the important factor? Did it work when you tried to just use single `float`s?

Comment: when i print and check numbers and gain seperately they both give the same float values. Calculation wise its correct. If possible help me with comparing of array values of different dimension. And j + 1 is used as i want ordering from 1 instead of 0

Comment: No even in single float it didnt work. I thought one is an array value(The value i need to compare belongs to an array) so the other one making it an array would help.

Comment: Oh and why are you using `float` for your numbers? There's really no need to do that, unless you have very specific requirements. Always use `double`.

Comment: *when i print and check numbers and gain seperately they both give the same float values* -- This is not how to determine the exactness of floating point numbers.  All printing does is print to a certain number of digits of precision.  When you use `==` to compare floating point numbers, *every* digit is used, including the least significant ones you are ignoring.  If you did this: `auto diff = numbers[i] - gain[i][j]; if ( diff == 0)` for values that you say are equal, is the `if` true or false?  If it's false, that's the reason why you don't see the items as equal -- floating point issues.

Comment: There is no difference at all between array elements and other objects of the same type. And `x + 1 == y + 1`  is equivalent to `x == y` regardless of whether you start counting from 0 or 1 or 1124.

Answer (score 0):

The direct comparison of floating-point numbers can be problematic due to precision limitations.

Instead of directly comparing with `==`, check if the absolute difference is below a small threshold:

```
const float EPSILON = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon; //

bool compFloat(float a, float b) {
    return std::abs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using [`std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) instead of making up your own.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it's a great suggestion. I recommend OP also look into the example code in the documentation of numeric limits for further insights https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon.